# SQL Injection at CakePHP 2.0

Tags: sql, cakephp, sql-injection, cakephp-2.0, code-injection

When someone execute this url at my website data at "post" table is deleted:

http://mysite.com/posts/getPosts/29;SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;delete from posts;

or

http://mysite.com/posts/getPosts/29;set foreign_key_checks = 0;

Currently the function at PostController is this:

```
public function getPosts($idUser, $return = true){
    $idUser = Sanitize::clean($idUser);     

    //calling Post Model...
    $posts = $this->Post->getPosts($idUser);
```

}

And yeah... im sorry but  i have an SQL sentence at Post Model called "getPosts". (but i can not change it now...)

I thought that with Sanitize would be enought...
How can i solve it?? Is there anything equivalent to mysql_real_escape_string at CakePHP when i work with my own SQL functions?

Thanks.

Comment: What leads you to believe that someone SQL injected here? Cake automatically protects against this. (Also, tag injection != sql injection.)

Comment: I am not sure where it can be. I am not sure if it's an SQL injection but i dont know any other method to drop a table. 
Any idea how to fight vs this? Thanks.

Comment: You have to prove that someone/thing is causing the table to be dropped for us to help. Logs, test cases that show your methods work, etc.

Comment: I've updated my question. Take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the logs, we're getting closer. Again, Cake will escape the string *for* you. Obviously there is more to your function if the table is being deleted. Or it's in `Post::getPosts()` when you haven't shown. You say "my own SQL functions" so please show them.

Comment: I solved it using a "is_numeric()". Anyway, it doesn't matter anymore.
For the next time i will use Cake models correctly :) Thanks for all.

Answer (score 2):

CakePHP 2.x will protect against SQL injection as long as you use the built-in query builders like `find` and `save`.

If your table IDs are integer there is a quick and easy hack that makes for good security. Use PHP's integer type converter on the parameter. It will either convert to the correct ID value or zero. There is no need to sanitize an integer value.

```
public function getPosts($idUser, $return = true)
{
    $posts = $this->Post->getPosts((int)$idUser);
}
```

I do this all the time in my models and it's a good habit to develop.

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing there is so awefully wrong and has nothing to do with sql injection whatsoever.
you are panicking and barking up the wrong tree here.

a) you dont need utf8_decode() - use utf8 throughout

b) you dont need strip_tags() - use h() instead in the view

c) you dont need sanitize - as unnecessary as strip_tags

d) your code is secure against SQL injection because you use save().

BUT

your code might not be secure against form tempering.

so you should enforce whitelisting or some other basic security measures like using the security component at least.

for more details on how to actually make a difference:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/09/21/saving-model-data-and-security/

Comment: I've updated my question. The bug was not on there. Anyway, i dont know how to solve it yet.